# Google ML prediction : 1 prediction with large dataset vs multiple smaller predictions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to design how my system uses Google ML for predictions.

I have a largish set of images I need to use for prediction.  I can either:

- send one big dataset to Google ML, and have the model break the data up into smaller iterative datasets, or
- break the dataset up before-hand and send multiple Google ML prediction requests with the smaller datasets.  This will ensure parallelism, but I'll end up sending about 3X the data.

If I allocate more resources for Google ML, will Google ML automatically parallelize the iterative datasets if I do option 1?  Or am I better off handling this myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What data format are you using?

Comment: @rhaertel80 in both cases, I'll be using a json with binary keyed values (for the images) as well as corresponding keyed float array values (for calibration values).

Comment: From the question, it sounds like you are doing batch prediction. How big is the dataset and what is your expectation on how quickly you see the results? For instance, the batch prediction service is a high throughput, file in/file out interface that may be appropriate here.

Comment: @rhaertel80 thanks for pointing out batch mode.  A typical dataset would be about 100 images.  In general, ideal latency between jobs should be less than 1-2 seconds.  So, with batch mode in mind, I'll go ahead with my second option of separating the prediction into multiple predictions, and just sending file locations for batch prediction.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: a batch prediction job typically takes 5-10 minutes for setup and teardown, so if you are aiming for 1-2 seconds, it may not be appropriate. On the other hand, you can send it a single file and let the workers atuoscale to maximize throughput. Online prediction can work for 100 images, but the biggest (current) bottleneck is that the payload size is limited to 1.5MB. Currently, you cannot read (non-public) files from GCS from online prediction (there's no way to set credentials), but we're fixing that in the next month.

Comment: @rhaertel80 regarding batch, I'm fine with long setup and teardown times as long as they are infrequent.  If I send two batch commands within a couple minutes, would the second batch set require its own setup / teardown?

Comment: @rhaertel80 regarding online payload size, is this for the total input size for a prediction?  I have to send 4-5 images per prediction.  Is there any way to get around the 1.5MB restriction for online?  Thanks!

Comment: @rhaertel80 it looks like I'll be able to split my model into two smaller models, and run two sequential online commands.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Batch prediction setup/tear down is per-job, so you'd want to try to put all the data into the same job (whether a single file or multiple files). We will be aiming to increase the online payload size, but for the time being it can't be increased. It may help to send resized+compressed images.

Comment: @rhaertel80 I took a look at splitting up the model a bit. Unfortunately, even with compression, the minimum payload I can use is 3.0 MB. When will the payload be increased? Also, when will the batch prediction setup/teardown times be decreased?  How would I access public files in GCS for an online prediction?  Just using the GCS url? Thanks!

Comment: The shortest term solution is to access GCS files. It will be available in a couple of weeks. Reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com for more info.